# Example relating to 'Symbol' in R vs. Console Practice

Tags: r, symbols

I am just learning R. Based on meaning of 'Symbol' in "R Language Definition' of CRAN, I wanted to explore further. Hence I googled. From a University's Website, I got the following examples:

Examples

```
an <- as.name("arrg")
is.name(an) # TRUE
mode(an)   # name
typeof(an) # symbol
```

When I practiced in the console, I am getting the following:

```
an <- as.name("arrgs")
is.name("an")
# [1] FALSE
mode("an")
# [1] "character"
typeof("an")
# [1] "character"
```

Could you kindly relate the second one with the first one?
Thank you for taking time..

Answer (score 0):

You did

```
is.name("an")
```

with quotes but the first example uses

```
is.name(an)
```

without quotes. When you use quotes, you are passing a character literal value, not a symbol.

But it's also useful to distinguish between symbols and the values they point to. So if you did

```
an <- "arrgs"
is.name(an)
# [1] FALSE
mode(an)
# [1] "character"
typeof(an)
```

So here technically `an` is a symbol, but that symbol is evaluated to see what it points to when running the functions. So here `an` is a symbol that points to a character value. You can see that if you look at the results from parsing the function calls

```
getParseData(parse(text='is.name(an)'))
#   line1 col1 line2 col2 id parent                token terminal    text
# 9     1    1     1   11  9      0                 expr    FALSE        
# 1     1    1     1    7  1      3 SYMBOL_FUNCTION_CALL     TRUE is.name
# 3     1    1     1    7  3      9                 expr    FALSE        
# 2     1    8     1    8  2      9                  '('     TRUE       (
# 4     1    9     1   10  4      6               SYMBOL     TRUE      an
# 6     1    9     1   10  6      9                 expr    FALSE        
# 5     1   11     1   11  5      9                  ')'     TRUE       )
```

but you can compare that to

```
getParseData(parse(text='is.name("an")'))
#   line1 col1 line2 col2 id parent                token terminal    text
# 9     1    1     1   13  9      0                 expr    FALSE        
# 1     1    1     1    7  1      3 SYMBOL_FUNCTION_CALL     TRUE is.name
# 3     1    1     1    7  3      9                 expr    FALSE        
# 2     1    8     1    8  2      9                  '('     TRUE       (
# 4     1    9     1   12  4      6            STR_CONST     TRUE    "an"
# 6     1    9     1   12  6      9                 expr    FALSE        
# 5     1   13     1   13  5      9                  ')'     TRUE       )
```